# Convert string to a parameterized type in scala

Tags: scala, casting

I am trying to convert string to scala `type` by using asInstanceof method,  while executing this am getting below exception
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2`

my code as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val cond : String = "(null, col(field).isNotNull)"  // Will get this condition from properties file.
type mutliColumnType = (Column, Column)

def condition( value : String , field : String = "somefield") : mutliColumnType = {
value match {
   case "a" => (null, col(field).isNull) 
   case _ => convertStringToMutliColumnType(cond) //cond.asInstanceOf[mutliColumnType]  
  }
}

condition("a") // returns data
condition("ab") // Exception
```

How can we convert string to `multiColumnType` here ?

UPDATE:

Currently I written below code snippet to parse string to `mutliColumnType` :

```
def convertStringToMutliColumnType(cond : String) : mutliColumnType = {
    val colArray=cond.trim.substring(1, cond.length-1).split(",")
    (col(colArray(0)), col(colArray(1)))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be wanting `asInstanceOf` to evaluate a string as Scala code. This isn't really the same thing as "casting", it's not what `asInstanceOf` does, and in fact evaluating strings as code is not something Scala supports at all (apart from some internal APIs and ill-advised libraries like the now-defunct twitter-util-eval).

It's quite unclear what you're trying to do here, but your options are basically either to write a parser that takes strings and returns `mutliColumnType` values (which is a lot of work and almost certainly a bad idea), or just not to do this—i.e. to use Scala code where you need Scala code and strings where you need strings.

As a footnote: `asInstanceOf` is only really useful for downcasting (when you've lost type information and have something typed as `Any` that you as the programmer "know" is actually a `String` or whatever), and even then it should be considered an advanced technique that's unsafe and not generally idiomatic. Any time you write `asInstanceOf` you're telling the compiler to get out of the way because you know better, and in my experience you'll generally be wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I realised that asInstanceOf is not to use here. I am not getting any idea how can I parse `cond` to `mutliColumnType`.  Could you please give me an approach to parse this?

Comment: @Giri In general I don't think "just don't do that" is a helpful SO answer, but in this case I don't think there's a better one. I'd suggest opening another question that describes what you're trying to accomplish at a higher level.